# selection mode single and multiple for same DataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

The below code is datatable and  based on Qustion type (property of Question object) user can either select one option or multiple options.

```
<p:dataTable id="optTable" value="#{indexBean.currentQuestion.options}" var="opt"
                                         selection="#{indexBean.currentQuestion.selectedOpt}"  >

                                <p:column  selectionMode="single" rendered="#{indexBean.currentQuestion.question.selectionMode eq 'single'}" />
                                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" rendered="#{indexBean.currentQuestion.question.selectionMode eq 'multiple'}" />
```

My problem is how to declare *selectedOpt* `(selection="#{indexBean.currentQuestion.selectedOpt}")` in my indexbean so that it can fit for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by making one column Single Selection Mode and the other Multiple Selection Mode.

The dataTable has the property selectionMode, column tag does not have such a property (at least not as of 2.2.1).

For an example of how to use the dataTable see the Primefaces Showcase, http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf

Comment: Actually I am developing a Quiz kind of Application. Where User might select either one option or more than one option depends on the Question type. I am using Data table to display list of options as shown in my question.  How can i achieve this

Comment: Make the Data Table selectionMode multiple per the showcase I linked above.  Start by trying to recreate the simple scenario of the showcase in your application and then expand on that functionality after you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Use **columnGroup**  with this example:

```
<p:dataTable  resizableColumns="false" id="multiTasks" var="task" rowStyleClass="#{task.id le 10 ? 'green' : (task.id le 20 ? 'yellow' : 'red')}" value="#{taskController.subjects}" rowKey="#{task.name}">   
                            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column headerText="Operations" />  
                                    <p:column headerText="Name fragment" />  
                                    <p:column headerText="View fragment" />  
                                    <p:column headerText="Consistency" />  
                                </p:row>
                            </p:columnGroup>
                            <p:column rendered="#{task.id le 10}" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%; text-align: center;" styleClass="text-right" />  
                            <p:column rendered="#{task.id gt 10 and task.id le 20 }" style="width:2%; text-align: center;" >
                                   <a href="activityForm.html">Recover this fragment</a>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column rendered="#{task.id gt 20 }" style="width:2%; text-align: center;" >
                               ---
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column id="nameTask" sortBy="#{task.name}" filterBy="#{task.name}" >
                                #{task.name}"
                            </p:column>   
                            <p:column id="viewFragment" style="text-align: center;" sortBy="#{task.name}" filterBy="#{task.name}" >
                                <p:button id="btnView" icon="ui-icon-search"></p:button>
                            </p:column>   
                            <p:column id="percentageConsistency"  sortBy="#{task.name}" filterBy="#{task.name}" >
                                #{(task.id le 10 ? '75%':(task.id le 20 ? '50%' : '25%'))}"
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
```

This works :D.